# Question about modulus order of operations

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have maybe a simple question but I haven't been able to find an answer through googling.

The question is as such:

Is $\ a × b^2 \bmod  c $ the same as $\ (a \bmod c) × (b^2 \bmod  c) $?

That's it. That's all I'm confused about.

Sorry if it seems a little simple...

`answer:`

> $\ a × b^2 \bmod c = ((a \bmod  c) × (b^2 \bmod c))\bmod c $

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the second product even take place?  If it is over the integers then definitely no.  $$2 \times 3^2 \pmod 6$$ is zero but $$2 \pmod 6$$ and $$3 \pmod 6$$ are just two and three.  Thus their product will be 6.

If the second product is not taken over the integers, and everything is modulo c in the end, then it does not matter if you reduce $a$ and $b^2$ before or after you multiply.

Comment: so essentially $\ 88 × 6^2 \ mod \ 25 $ is only the same as $( (88 \ mod \ 25) × (6^2 \ mod \ 25) )  \ mod \ 25$ aka - you modulo everything by $c $ in the end?

Comment: Correct!  The rule that makes this work is often written as follows:

If $a \equiv b$ and $c \equiv d$ then $ac \equiv bd$, where everything is modulo $n.$  This says that we can switch and multiply, or multiply and switch.  So long as everything is modulo $n$ in the end you'll get the same result.

Comment: thank you, that really clarifies it!

Answer (score 0):

Generally no. Distributive property here does not apply although there would be coincidental instance when it will hold.

Let

$ab^2\bmod c= r$

$a\bmod c= p$

$b^2\bmod c= q$

Then your question would imply that $r=pq$

Where
$$r=\frac {ab^2}{lc}$$
$$p=\frac {a}{mc}$$
$$q=\frac {b^2}{nc}$$

$l,m,n$ are integers

Thus implies

$$r=\frac{ab^2}{lc}=(\frac{a}{mc})(\frac{b^2}{nc})=\frac{ab^2}{mnc^2}$$
Only **true** when $l=mnc$

Comment: what about, $\ a × b^2 \ mod \ c $  =  $( (a \ mod \ c) × (b^2 \ mod \ c)) \ mod \ c$?

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: Thank you! Seems so simple now. I'm still wrapping my head around modulo, thank you for the patience.

Comment: wait, sorry, so... $88 × 6^2\ mod\ 25 = ((88\ mod\ 25) × (6^2\ mod\ 25))\ mod\ 25$ is **coincidental**? It wouldn't hold true for just any combination?

Comment: What i said about **coincidental** was about your original question which would hold true if certain condition is met (that is $l=mnc$) as what I have shown.

Comment: phew, okay, just checking! I understand now, got it.